# Cannot implicitly convert type from IOrderedQueryable<T> to List<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I get the following error on the `seminariolista =` line:

> Cannot implicitly convert type from IOrderedQueryable to List

```
public List<Seminario> Listarseminariomodal()
{
    var seminariolista = new List<Seminario>();
    try
    {
        using (var ctx = new ProyectoContext_())
        {
            seminariolista = ctx.Seminario.Where(x => x.modal == 1)
            .OrderBy(x => x.orden);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return seminariolista;
}
```

[Visual Studio Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmccA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Probably defining it as

```
IEnumerable<Seminario> seminariolista = null;
```

and returning it as

```
return seminariolista.ToList();
```

will work.

But in general it's not a good idea, in my opinion, to return a List object, unless you explicitly need it. I would return an IEnumeralble, to keep the method signature as general as possible.
So, the best solution for your code, in my opinion and WITHOUT KNOWING the requirement of your application and the rest of your code:

```
public IEnumerable<Seminario> Listarseminariomodal()
{
    IEnumerable<Seminario> seminariolista = null;
    try
    {
        using (var ctx = new ProyectoContext_())
        {
            seminariolista = ctx.Seminario.Where(x => x.modal == 1)
            .OrderBy(x => x.orden);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return seminariolista.ToArray();
}
```

Note the `ToArray()` call at the end, to hide the LINQ stuff outside the method body.